# App/web app for workers on the field. Do I need internet?

Tags: android, ios, web

I need to create a simple app for civil engineer.
It will be a simple app, with a simple form that a worker on the field will fill out and save the info in a database.
Sometimes the user may don't have access to internet.

For what I've seen, I have two options:

1-> create a simple website, and the user can access to the website wherever he has internet
2-> create an app, more than like it for android platforms.

Is there anyway to make it so that the app doesn't need internet to work?

thanks

Comment: Sure; save to a local database and sync when internet becomes available again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using nsuserdefaults to save the text or what ever you need to save locally and you could use an if statement to check for Internet connection if not then it saves it locally or you could have it do both( or a least try and you will have it saved at least in one place).  Or you could use the local store temporarily until you get to wifi and then it saves like the comment above says. Good luck!